# Is it more performant to index in the vertex shader or fragment shader?

Tags: glsl, performance, webgl

I have a shader that draws 2D quads from a texture atlas using instancing. I'd like to add a feature that allows me to map each of the RGBA channels in the texture using a 5x5 matrix. For example, the following would swap the red and green channels:

```
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

I only need a few of these transformations, so my plan is to provide them to the GPU as a uniform and then index into this by passing an attribute to my shader for each quad. I think there are two approaches I could take:

1. Look up the 5x5 matrix once in the vertex shader and pass it to the fragment shader as a varying
2. Pass the index to the fragment shader as a varying and look up the matrix in the fragment shader

I'm not sure which of these approaches would be more performant. My inclination is 1, because then the lookup only has to happen once per instance, but does that mean there's more overhead in passing 25 floating point numbers via the varying?

By the way, my graphics pipeline is WebGL if that makes a difference.

Comment: "Which is more performant, option A or option B?" is a class of question that you can answer both faster and more authoritatively than waiting for Internet strangers' hearsay, by quickly coding up a test of each option and profiling the results. That way you'll get real, measurable evidence that you know applies perfectly to your situation. This last bit is especially important, because trade-offs like this can shift depending on whether your particular application is compute-bound, memory-bound, fillrate-bound, or otherwise has a different resource contention situation than an answer assumes.

Comment: I'll try to put some profiling in if I can figure out how to do that. I'm not really sure what edits I'd make to refine it and I really want to just get on work this problem through now. Thanks again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106281/discussion-on-question-by-chris-is-it-more-performant-to-index-in-the-vertex-sha).

Comment: Sounds like it wouldn't matter